# Issues to align elements the way I want

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align the elements of my header like on the first image below.
Unfortunately I'm not getting the expected result. The female sign and the image next to it stay stuck to the top of the page.
I've tried to apply a margin-top but the issue if I do that is that it pushes everything else down.
Your help would be much appreciated.
I haven't been able to reproduce this on JSFfiddle, so here is the [live link](http://goo.gl/8pG9HX).
Many thanks,

**This is what I want (female sign aligned just above the text):**

[image]

**This is what I have:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting *position* to *absolute* and then *top* to *200px* I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue with using top is that depending on the viewport height the female sign could be places below the john smith text, which is not what I want. Ideally I'd like it to be placed X pixels above the text, so that no matter what the viewport height is, it will always be placed above the john smith text

Comment: You can set the "john smith text" in a DIV with absolute position too

Answer (score 0):

use `position: relative;` and change `top` value. Replace this classes:

```
.female-sign {
  position: relative;
  top: 263px;
  left: 65px;
}
```

and

```
.special-femmes {
  position: relative;
  top: 230px;
  left: 65px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue with using top is that depending on the viewport height the female sign could be placed below the john smith text, which is not what I want. Ideally I'd like it to be placed X pixels above the john smith text, so that no matter what the viewport height is, it will always be placed above the john smith text